# FileProvider vs MediaStore content URI

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to build some basic file manager to browse external storage files on my **Android P** device. I have **two methods** that create intents to open files **using outside apps**. Both methods are **the same** except the **Uri** part.

One of them using **FileProvider** to create Uri from a file, which looks like this:

```
content://com.myapp.FILE_PROVIDER/external_files/6537-6630/DCIM/Camera/20180727_221149.jpg
```

The other one queries **MediaStore** and returns Uri that looks like this:

```
content://media/external/images/media/3273
```

The rest of the code is identical

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
startActivity(intent);
```

Both URIs are valid, however when I open images (random images from external storage) using the one that is created with **FileProvider** they are opened with **read-only access** in outside apps. I can tell that because I don't get the editing options. The image from the Uri using MediaStore is opened as expected, with write access and thus the editing options.

I also downloaded a couple of File Managers from the Play store. This one for example: [File Manager - Local and Cloud File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cvinfo.filemanager) (I guess it is using FileProvider) has the same read-only access problem when opening images.

Code

```
    <provider
        android:name="com.myapp.files.MyFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.FILE_PROVIDER"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <root-path name="external_files" path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

**My questions are:**

**1. Do I miss something when using FileProvider? Maybe it is not intended for external storage files?**

**2. Are there other methods to get valid URIs for existing files? Because MediaStore doesn't have all the files**

Comment: "Maybe it is not intended for external storage files?" -- you might want to post your `res/xml/provider_paths.xml` resource. From the `Uri`, it looks like you are trying to use `FileProvider` for [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), which is unlikely to work well.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I tried it on every possible storage and it is always read only. provider_paths is included.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe it is not intended for external storage files?

You are not using it for [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). You are using it for [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

`<root-path>` is undocumented and unsupported. `FileProvider` will not work reliably for removable storage, because your app does not have access to arbitrary filesystem locations on removable storage. My guess is that if you try writing to that file in your app — whether using the `File` or the `Uri` — you will fail with an error.

`MediaStore` has access to more of removable storage, because it is part of the OS.

> Are there other methods to get valid URIs for existing files?

You are welcome to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and ask the user to choose their removable storage. You can then:

- Use `takePersistableUriPermission()` to get long-term access to the document tree that the user chose
- Use `DocumentFile` to traverse that document tree and get `Uri` values for documents in it

Just bear in mind that the user does not have to choose their removable storage — they are welcome to choose any document tree that they want. Done properly, this can be a feature, not a bug, in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This particular Uri that I posted is indeed from the sd card, but thing is I tried it on other images from every folder on my device - same result.